# JAVA Find the shortest reverse path in a graph using Dijkstra

Tags: java, path, reverse, shortest-path, dijkstra

I come here with a small problem. I have to find the shortest path in a graph, but also the shortest reverse path. I am having trouble computing the reverse path. For example I have to find a route from B to D, but I can't seem to figure out how to find the shortest path from D to B. The paths are unidirectional.

This is my code down here:
To run this, just use something like "2, B20, D" where the first char is the number of passengers, the second item is the airport and miles from home to airport and finally, D is the destination.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.jar.JarOutputStream;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;
    public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public int compareTo(Vertex other)
    {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}


class Edge
{
    public final Vertex target;
    public final double weight;
    public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight)
    { target = argTarget; weight = argWeight; }
}

public class Flights
{
    public static void computePaths(Vertex source)
    {
        source.minDistance = 0.;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
        vertexQueue.add(source);

        while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

            // Visit each edge exiting u
            for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
            {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
                if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                    vertexQueue.remove(v);

                    v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
                    v.previous = u;
                    vertexQueue.add(v);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
    {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
            path.add(vertex);

        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Vertex v0 = new Vertex("0");
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex("1");
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex("2");
        Vertex v3 = new Vertex("3");
        Vertex v4 = new Vertex("4");
        Vertex v5 = new Vertex("5");
        Vertex v6 = new Vertex("6");
        v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1,  800),//AB800
                                     new Edge(v5,  200)};//AF200
        v1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0,  700),//BA700
                                     new Edge(v2,  900),//BC900
                                     new Edge(v5,  400),//BF400
                                     new Edge(v6,  800)};//BG800
        v2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v3,  400),//CD400
                                     new Edge(v4,  300),//CE300
                                     new Edge(v4,  200)};//CE200
        v3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v4,  400),//DE400
                                     new Edge(v4,  300),//DE300
                                     new Edge(v2,  700) };//DC700
        v4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1,  600) };//EB600
        v5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0,  300),//FA300
                                     new Edge(v3,  200),//FD200
                                     new Edge(v4,  500),//FE500
                                     new Edge(v6,  700) };//FG700
        v6.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v3,  600),//GD600
                                     new Edge(v5,  400) };//GF400




        String[] nameNumber = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};
        Vertex[] vertices = { v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 };
        HashMap<String, Vertex> dict = new HashMap<String, Vertex>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nameNumber.length; i++)
        {
            dict.put(nameNumber[i], vertices[i]);
        }

        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter input journey:");
        String inputJourney = k.nextLine();

        String homeToAirport = inputJourney.split(", ")[1];
        String airport = String.valueOf(homeToAirport.charAt(0));
        String airportdestination = inputJourney.split(", ")[2];

        int passengers = Integer.parseInt(inputJourney.split(", ")[0]);
        String modifiedString= inputJourney.substring(1);

        int milesToAirport= Integer.parseInt(modifiedString.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
        int car = ((20 * Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(milesToAirport)))) / 100;
        int parking = 3;
        int taxi = (40 * Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(milesToAirport)))/100;



        if (dict.containsKey(airport)) {

            computePaths(vertices[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dict.get(airport)))]);
            double outboundFlightCost= (10 * vertices[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dict.get(airportdestination)))].minDistance * passengers)/100;
            System.out.println("Outbound Flight cost: " + outboundFlightCost);

            computePaths(vertices[Integer.parseInt((String.valueOf(dict.get(airportdestination))))]);
            double inboundFlightCost = (10 * vertices[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dict.get(airport)))].minDistance * passengers)/100;
            System.out.println("Inbound flight cost" + inboundFlightCost);
            List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(dict.get(airportdestination));
                System.out.println("Path is: " + path);
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting question, but this example could be made more [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and easily answerable. For example, remove all the input/console UI and hard code a few simple test cases and their expected output.

Comment: Fair enough. I haven't used Java in a long time, so I am quite inefficient at the moment. I did this in a very short time frame so there are definitely some optimizations needed. I'll see what I can do in the mean time. Will try to edit the code.

Comment: Beyond that, from the looks of it, you're running an identical algorithm from B->D as D->B, so are you sure everything is set up properly? Maybe you can strip out some code and try to target the problem.